# Optionals with @ObservedObject and @Published var

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui

I am getting quite mad with unwrapping optionals on a SwiftUI project. The project has (removed extra lines for readability):

```swift
struct Report: Decodable {
    var siteId: String = "nosite"

    enum ReportKeys: String, CodingKey { //some keys here
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // all the code for remapping json properties to the struct
    }
}

class ReportCaller: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var lastReport: Report?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        loadReport()
    }
    
    func loadReport() { 
        // URL session code that finally returns
        self.lastReport =  try! decoder.decode(Report, from: data)
    }
```

The, in my view, I have

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var report = ReportCaller()
```

Now, to make it working, I must unwrap each line, as below:

```
Text(report.lastReport?.siteId ?? "")
```

The struct has defaults, so I would expect to not unwrap anything. I recognize I miss some initialization, but I cannot figure out where I should put it. The `@ObservedObject` calls a class, it seems not the place where to do it. Because the class publishes an optional `Report?`, I thought to remove the optional there, but I get another problem:

```swift
Property 'self.lastReport' not initialized at super.init call
```

I can try to make

```swift
    override init() {
        self.lastReport = Metar()
        super.init()
        loadReport()
    }
```

Although the compiler complains the `from:` is missing, because this is effectively what the `init` in the struct expects. So, I am getting confused on which should be the best way to manage the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is apparently to extend my own struct and provide a default init

```swift
struct Report: Decodable {
    var siteId: String
    enum ReportKeys: String, CodingKey { //some keys here
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // all the code for remapping json properties to the struct
    }

    init() {
        self.siteId = "nosite"
    }
}
```

This allows to call a default init of the struct, which can happen without decoding anything, and removes the need to unwrap, because there is a default for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `()` after ReportCaller. I'm using a very similar approach that doesn't with `()`. The code should look like this, I believe:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var report: ReportCaller
```